# get the current time in seconds

Tags: c

I am wondering is there any function that would return the current time in seconds, just 2 digits of seconds? I'm using gcc 4.4.2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following complete program shows you how to access the seconds value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    time_t now;
    struct tm *tm;

    now = time(0);
    if ((tm = localtime (&now)) == NULL) {
        printf ("Error extracting time stuff\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
        tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_mon+1, tm->tm_mday,
        tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
2010-02-11 15:58:29
```

How it works is as follows.

- it calls `time()` to get the best approximation to the current time (usually number of seconds since the epoch but that's not actually mandated by the standard).
- it then calls `localtime()` to convert that to a structure which contains the individual date and time fields, among other things.
- at that point, you can just de-reference the structure to get the fields you're interested in (`tm_sec` in your case but I've shown a few of them).

Keep in mind you can also use `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()` if you want Greenwich time, or UTC for those too young to remember :-).

Comment: @robUK Just in case you will use this code in a multithreaded application with lots of threads getting seconds in this way. Is is likely that `localtime` use one global mutex in its work (while accessing global locale object). So if you use it in a function that is often called your threads will spend their time waiting in `pthread_mutex_unloc()`

Comment: It's possibly worse than that, @skwlisp. Unless the return value is a pointer to a thread-specific object, you may find it corrupted. In a threaded environment, you should probably use the "_r" variants of unsafe calls. I just didn't want to clutter up my answer with a possibly unnecessary detail.

Comment: I've been working on a Standard C Library implementation recently, and wanted to add a few details.  `time()` doesn't necessarily return the number of seconds since the epoch (but it does on most platforms).  And `tm_sec` can range from 0 to 61 (to account for leap seconds).

Comment: That's a good point, @tomlogic, I wasn't aware the standard stated the "best approximation" nor that it had made the encoding implemetation-specific. Modified to suit. I think the range of tm_sec is actually 0 thru 60 rather than 61 though, but that's probably just a typo on your part. The crux of your point is made: it may not _always_ be 0 thru 59.

Comment: If the standard C documentation (e.g. c99, c11, c17) doesn't mandate that `time(...)` has to return current time in seconds , how can I ensure the unit (e.g. milliseconds) of the return value in `time(...)` ? I am reading the stardard docs (c17 and GCC) but have not found anything explicitly describing the detail , which is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

A more portable way to do this is to get the current time as a `time_t` struct:

```
time_t mytime = time((time_t*)0);
```

Retrieve a `struct tm` for this `time_t`:

```
struct tm *mytm = localtime(&mytime);
```

Examine the `tm_sec` member of `mytm`. Depending on your C library, there's no guarantee that the return value of `time()` is based on a number of seconds since the start of a minute.

Comment: `time_t mytime((time_t*)0);` is invalid in C and has a type mismatch in C++.  Did you mean `time_t mytime = time(0);`?

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: Yes, thanks. I've been doing too much C++ and then forgot the crucial `time` call itself. (Actually, I forgot the variable name originally but messed up fixing it while writing the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current time with `gettimeofday` (C11), `time` (Linux), or `localtime_r` (POSIX); depending on what calendar & epoch you're interested. You can convert it to seconds elapsed after calendar epoch, or seconds of current minute, whichever you are after:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t current_secs = time(NULL);
    localtime_r(&current_secs, &current_time);

    char secstr[128] = {};
    struct tm current_time;
    strftime(secstr, sizeof secstr, "%S", &current_time);

    fprintf(stdout, "The second: %s\n", secstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use gettimeofday:

man 2 gettimeofday

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int iRet;
  struct timeval tv;

  iRet = gettimeofday (&tv, NULL); // timezone structure is obsolete
  if (iRet == 0)
  {
    printf ("Seconds/USeconds since epoch: %d/%d\n",
            (int)tv.tv_sec, (int)tv.tv_usec);
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    perror ("gettimeofday");
  }

  return iRet;
}
```

This is better to use then time(0), because you get the useconds as well, atomically, which is the more common use case.