# Executing unix commands in C++

Tags: c++, unix

Is there a way to use the unix 'time' command in C++ and store each of its outputs in a variable?

EDIT: If there isn't a way, then what about calling time in a bash script and storing the returned values some way?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you don't want to use the `time` function, and the various functions that format `time_t` variables? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242963/get-the-current-time-in-seconds.

Comment: Yes, I tried a few such functions - I had a problem to compile clock_gettime, and all the other time functions I tried that did compile had other problems. time() for example gave me diff in integer, others gave me diff in double but it was the CPU time and not clock time (the 'real' in the unix time command).

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are on UNIX, then the C++ standard `std::system` function will behave as [defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html), that is, execute a command as with `sh`. Before doing this, you can connect your own `stdin` and `stdout` to a local pipe by first using `dup` to create aliases of `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO`, then `close` the aforementioned file descriptors, then `pipe` to open a pipe on the newly freed descriptors.

Then you can interact with `std::cin` and `std::cout`. Well, it would be a good idea to flush the C++ interface before beginning.

This isn't all really a good idea, though. It should be simpler to use the POSIX C interface to get the relevant data directly.

Comment: As you mention, I'm looking for a simpler solution. But it's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using Boost libraries, then this should do it http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch

the good part is it also handles time zones conversions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) or [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), but there's almost always a better, more portable, and native solution, depending on what exactly you're looking for.   In your specific case it seems like what you're really looking for a combination of [`getrusage(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) and [`ftime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftime).